# GXT grid header width unaligned with content if scrollbar visible

Tags: gwt, gxt, grid-layout

I have a display problem with my gxt grids (GXT 2.3.1, `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid`). It is only visible if horizontal and vertical scrollbars are present: As you can see on the screenshot, the header is missing a space on the right side (above the scrollbar). This causes that header to be unaligned with the columns. The issue isn't easy to reproduce and occurs quite randomly, sometime after the grid has been resized.

This is also reproducible with GXT3: https://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:remotefiltergrid (you have to change the grid and column size to reproduce)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `GridView.calculateVBar` method: It looks like the grid content could fit into the scroller if there was no horizontal scroll bar. So gxt thinks that the header needs no vertical scroll bar and no spacer on the right side. But as there are scroll bars the header is displayed wrongly.

Overriding `calculateVBar` (in order to take the horizontal scrollbar height into account) in an inherited class solves the problem.